# MvvmCross Android Dialog bind programmatically

Tags: binding, android-dialog, mvvmcross

I want to use the Android.Dialog (`Cross.UI`) in my MvvmCross project. My first approach was to use AutoViews. As this feature is still fairly young, the alternative was to implement the dialog in touch and Droid platforms.

For now i'm just doing this for Droid and I need to programmatically bind the properties of the ViewModel to the elements of the Dialog.

My View and ViewModel code is the following:

### View

```
    public class DialogConfigurationView : MvxBindingDialogActivityView<DialogConfigurationViewModel>
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            DroidResources.Initialise(typeof(Resource.Layout));

            Root = new RootElement()
                {
                    new Section("Private Configuration")
                        {
                            new EntryElement("Name:"),
                            new EntryElement("Description:"),
                            new BooleanElement("Active?")
                        }
                };
        }
    }
```

### ViewModel

```
    public class DialogConfigurationViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        public ConfigurationSet Configuration
        {
            get { return _configuration; }
            set
            {
                if (_configuration != value)
                {
                    _configuration = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Configuration);
                }
            }
        }
        private ConfigurationSet _configuration;
    }
```

My goal is to have a twoway bind the `EntryElement("Name:")` with the property `ViewModel.Configuration.Name`.

Can anyone help me with this? Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there are any monodroid.dialog mvvmcross samples floating around which don't use autoviews!

However.... the basic syntac for binding should be the same as MonoTouch.Dialog - e.g. something like:

```
                            new Section("Contact Info")
                                {
                                    new StringElement("ID", ViewModel.Customer.ID ?? string.Empty),
                                    new EntryElement("Name", "Name").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Customer.Name'}}"),
                                    new EntryElement("Website", "Website").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Customer.Website'}}"),
                                    new EntryElement("Primary Phone", "Phone").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Customer.PrimaryPhone'}}"),
                                },
                            new Section("Primary Address")
                                {
                                    new EntryElement("Address").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Customer.PrimaryAddress.Street1'}}"),
                                    new EntryElement("Address2").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Customer.PrimaryAddress.Street2'}}"),
                                    new EntryElement("City").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Customer.PrimaryAddress.City'}}"),
                                    new EntryElement("State").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Customer.PrimaryAddress.State'}}"),
                                    new EntryElement("Zip").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Customer.PrimaryAddress.Zip'}}"),
                                },
```

from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Sample%20-%20CustomerManagement/CustomerManagement/CustomerManagement.Touch/Views/BaseCustomerEditView.cs

---

Note that in MvvmCross bindings for MonoTouch and MonoDroid, the default binding for things like text edit boxes is generally `TwoWay` by default.

---

If you do get a sample running, then please feel free to post it to a gist or to a repo - or to blog about it - looks like we could do with some samples to work from!

Comment: I'll definitely look into this. I'll post my results as soon as I get this example to work. Thanks!

Comment: It seems there were a few things missing... but this seems to work now I've added them :) See commit https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/commit/1e06da6732db1e99eeba5e3b6aa1042796d63f5f Thanks a lot for finding this missing gap!

Comment: I'm the one that has to say Thank You! The problem was solved even before I start to look at him... :) Tomorrow morning I'll update my fork and after that I can post a working sample