# MvvmCross Android Dialog Bing Programmatically - ViewModel is not updated

Tags: binding, notifications, viewmodel, mvvmcross

This is a follow up of the post about [MvvmCross Android Dialog Bing Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384229/mvvmcross-android-dialog-bind-programmatically)

I've implemented the bindings of a Dialog in a Droid project:

```
    this.Root = new RootElement("Customer Info")
    {
        new Section("Private Configuration")
        {
            new EntryElement("Pin:").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Configuration.Pin'}}"),
            new EntryElement("Name:").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Configuration.Name', 'Mode':'TwoWay'}}"),
        };
    };
```

I've added the *TwoWay* in the `Configuration.Name` bind just for test purposes.

The problem now is that the bind is working only in *OneWay*. The object is **not updated if I change something in the view**, but the **view is notified if the object is changed**. This happens in both binds described above (with or without *TwoWay* in bind *Mode*).

This is the only thing left to have a full Droid.Dialog project, working with bind and multiple views, controlled by viewModels, using MvvmCross framework.

From what I've been able to debug (only Droid code and no PCL, in VS2010), every time I change the text in the `EntryElement`, the *OnTextChanged* method is called and the property *Value* is beeing updated.

### EntryElement.cs

```
    public virtual void OnTextChanged(string newText)
    {
        //Log.Info("Just playing","New text:" + newText);
        OnUserValueChanged(newText);
    }
```

### ValueElement.cs

```
    protected void OnUserValueChanged(TValueType newValue)
    {
        Value = newValue;
        FireValueChanged();
    }

    protected virtual void FireValueChanged()
    {
        var handler = ValueChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

## Here's the code I have in core and droid projects

### CORE

**BaseViewModel.cs**

```
    public class BaseViewModel : MvxViewModel, IMvxServiceConsumer
    {
        protected IConfigurationDataStore ConfigDataStore
        {
            get
            {
                if (_configDataStore == null)
                    _configDataStore = this.GetService<IConfigurationDataStore>();

                return _configDataStore;
            }
        }
        private IConfigurationDataStore _configDataStore;
    }
```

**EditConfigurationViewModel.cs**

```
    public class EditConfigurationViewModel : BaseViewModel, IEditConfigurationViewModel
    {
        public ConfigurationSet Configuration
        {
            get { return _configuration; }
            set
            {
                if (_configuration != value)
                {
                    _configuration = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Configuration);
                }
            }
        }
        private ConfigurationSet _configuration;

        public EditConfigurationViewModel(string id)
        {
            Guid value;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) || !Guid.TryParse(id, out value))
            {
                Configuration = new ConfigurationSet();
            }
            else
            {
                Configuration = ConfigDataStore.GetConfiguration(value);
            }
        }

        public void SaveConfiguration()
        {
            ConfigDataStore.UpdateConfiguration(Configuration);
        }
    }
```

**ConfigurationSet.cs**

```
    public class ConfigurationSet : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Pin
        {
            get { return _pin; }
            set
            {
                if (_pin != value)
                {
                    _pin = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Pin);
                }
            }
        }
        private string _pin;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                //if (_name != value)
                //{
                    _name = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(()=> Name);
                //}
            }
        }
        private string _name;

        public string PrivateDescription
        {
            get { return _privateDescription; }
            set
            {
                if (_privateDescription != value)
                {
                    _privateDescription = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => PrivateDescription);
                }
            }
        }
        private string _privateDescription;
    }
```

### DROID

**EditConfigurationView**

```
    public class EditConfigurationView : MvxBindingDialogActivityView<EditConfigurationViewModel>, IMvxServiceConsumer
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            DroidResources.Initialise(typeof(Resource.Layout));

            Root = new RootElement()
                {
                    new Section("Private Configuration")
                    {
                        new EntryElement("Pin:").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Configuration.Pin'}}"),
                        new EntryElement("Name:").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Configuration.Name'}}"),
                        new EntryElement("Description:").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Configuration.PrivateDescription'}}")
                    }
                };
        }

        public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            ViewModel.SaveConfiguration();

            base.OnBackPressed();
        }

        protected override void OnViewModelSet()
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second answer after seeing your repo on https://github.com/zleao/MvvmCross.Dialog

---

Thanks for the additional information.

I've not run your sample yet, but seeing the simple code to reproduce the problem helps a lot.

I think the problem is probably in your Setup file - https://github.com/zleao/MvvmCross.Dialog/blob/master/MvvmCross.Dialog.UI.Droid/Setup.cs

The Setup there inherits from `MvxBaseAndroidBindingSetup` which is the base setup class for everything in `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid` and which itself inherits from `MvxBaseAndroidSetup` from `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid`

Since you are using the Dialog code in addition to "just Binding" then you need to take your setup further - you need to add `MvxBaseAndroidDialogBindingSetup` from `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Dialog.Droid`. This class adds a number of important steps including registering a two-way binding for `Value` on all `ValueElement` instances - see:

```
    protected override void FillTargetFactories(
        Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Interfaces.Bindings.Target.Construction.IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxPropertyInfoTargetBindingFactory(typeof (ValueElement), "Value",
                                                                         (element, propertyInfo) =>
                                                                         new MvxElementValueTargetBinding(element,
                                                                                                          propertyInfo)));
        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
    }
```

in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Dialog.Droid/MvxBaseAndroidDialogBindingSetup.cs

---

So - to try to fix the problem, try inheriting Setup from  `MvxBaseAndroidDialogBindingSetup`

---

For more info about the layers of MvvmCross, please see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/a-short-guide-to-layers-of-mvvmcross.html

---

I hope this helps and solves the problem.

Thanks for the excellent level of detail supplied.

Please do note, though, that the Droid.Dialog code is still quite young compared to the Touch Dialog code - so you may hit genuine bugs and problems along the way. When you hit them, please do ask question here, or if they are bugs, then please do log them on Issues on https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues?state=open

Stuart

Comment: I've just tested with the change you sugested, and the magic is all there now!!! :) I'll update the repo with a more complex and complete scenario, as soon as I can (hopefully tomorrow). Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested this with a modified CustomerManagement sample app - and this binding is working Two-Way fine for me.

My code:

```
        Root = new RootElement()
            {
                new Section("Customer Info")
                    {
                        new EntryElement("Name").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Customer.Name'}}"),
                        new EntryElement("Website").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Customer.Website'}}"),
                        new EntryElement("Phone").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Customer.PrimaryPhone'}}"),
                    }
            };
```

My ViewModel and Customer object are:

```
public abstract class BaseEditCustomerViewModel
    : BaseViewModel
{
    private Customer _customer;
    public Customer Customer
    {
        get { return _customer; }
        private set { _customer = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Customer"); }
    }

    // ...
}

public class Customer : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Customer()
    {
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    private string _website;
    public string Website
    {
        get { return _website; }
        set { _website = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Website"); }
    }

    private string _primaryPhone;
    public string PrimaryPhone
    {
        get { return _primaryPhone; }
        set { _primaryPhone = value; RaisePropertyChanged("PrimaryPhone"); }
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

From your description I couldn't spot any obvious errors - although obviously I can't see all the details - e.g. what is the Configuration object on the ViewModel side?

---

If you suspect this might be a bug, it's probably easiest to log these on https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/new

The more detail you can include with a bug the quicker it will get looked at - e.g. if you can include a sample github repo which reproduces the problem, then it's quick and easy for a developer to test. If, instead, you just provide instructions, then it might take a developer 1 or more hours to test - so you need to wait for them to have 'spare time'.

---

For the complaint about 'debug ... only Droid code and no PCL, in VS2010', please ensure you've raised this with Xamarin - the only way they will fix these things is if there paying customers tell them about problems.

Comment: I've edit the question and added the code I have in the 'Core' and 'Droid' projects. I'll prepare a sample to put in GitHub repo. Thanks

Comment: I've added a repo in GitHub with a very simple example of what I've described here. (https://github.com/zleao/MvvmCross.Dialog)

Answer (score 0):

this is also required in iOS.

```
public class Setup : MvxIosDialogSetup//MvxIosSetup
```